# Why on implementing 2 Mat-Table on same page Row color change and paginator not working?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular7

I have tried changing the color of row on edit click event with below code and is working fine

```
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceUsersTbl" class=" full-width users-grid" matSort>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="fullname">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="fullName-col" mat-sort-header> Full Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="fullName-col"> {{element.fullname}} </td>
     </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="action-col"> Actions </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="action-col">
        <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Edit" (click)="openEditDialog(element)">
       <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
        </button>          
       </td>
       </ng-container>
     <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsUsers; sticky: false"></tr>
     <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsUsers;" 
    [ngClass]="{ row-edited': selectedRowIndex == element.userid}"></tr>
   </table>
   <mat-paginator #MatPaginator1 [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons class="dino-grid-paging">
    </mat-paginator>
```

but when I add the second mat-table in same page it give issue as below

```
UsersMasterComponent.html:61 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property   'userid' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (UsersMasterComponent.html:62)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23910)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23306)
at callViewAction (core.js:23547)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:23510)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23307)
at callViewAction (core.js:23547)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:23489)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23312)
at callViewAction (core.js:23547)
```

also in 1st paginator grid it give row count of second grid row.

In component side I have also tried doing some code as below and distinquish them with MatPaginator1 and MatPaginator2 but still not working

```
@ViewChild('MatSort1') MatSort1: MatSort;
@ViewChild('MatPaginator1') MatPaginator1: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild('MatSort2') MatSort2: MatSort;
@ViewChild('MatPaginator2') MatPaginator2: MatPaginator;


ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSourceUsersTbl.sort = this.MatSort1;
  this.dataSourceUsersTbl.paginator = this.MatPaginator1;
  this.dataSourceAssignPermission.sort = this.MatSort1;
  this.dataSourceAssignPermission.paginator = this.MatPaginator2;
}
```

On edit click the color should change with giving issue and pagination should work well and sorting in second grid not working

Note : this issue arise when i implement 2 mat-table in one page, on applying single mat-table my things work fine.

For more information please review this link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c79ptl

Comment: could you make stackblitz? I would help with more code.

Comment: @Vato I have tred setting in stackblitz Can I have your email, I can send u the html file

Comment: @Vato please review this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c79ptl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try calling element in second table element2 or some other name than the first element. Not to have the same problem I would put each table in separate component and give the data required with @Input property.

Here you go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5fvdgj

you had to only write

```
@ViewChild('MatPaginator1') paginator: MatPaginator;
```

you have to do the same for MatPaginator2

and in html in front of MatPaginator1 you need # so that angular can find it by Id. you dont need

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator1) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

without ' ' is unnecessary.

You need to do the same for sort. But, Instead of #sort1 you need to write #matSort1="matSort" same for sort 2.

Comment: I need in same component

Comment: I included sort too. you don't have any logic on colors implemented of course it would not change anything.

Comment: I have also update my code, u can see the openEditDialog method imlement on edit button and a logic on component page

Comment: you never call openEditDialog from html. giving color is separate topic, its not related to this. search google or stackoverflow for that. or ask another question

Comment: Ok i will ask new and let u know

Comment: approve the answer.

Comment: as per the question Why on implementing 2 Mat-Table on same page Row color change and paginator not working?, row color is still not changing

Comment: row color is still not changing. You didn't implement any logic to change color. that's whole separate topic. you didn't show any research or effort to change the color. this is not a place for other people to write you projects. I gave answer to whatever you provided. your row colors don't work because there is no code for it to work. it seems like you haven't even tried to change the color. change your question to be appropriate and write another one for the colors. but show some effort first.

Comment: did u review this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c79ptl  I have implemented in same

Comment: open another question. change the title of this question. approve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@ViewChild('firstPaginator', {static: true}) firstPaginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild('secondPaginator', {static: true}) secondPaginator: MatPaginator;
```

In the HTML

```
<mat-paginator #firstPaginator [pageSize]="5"></mat-paginator>

<mat-paginator #secondPaginator [pageSize]="5"></mat-paginator>
```